# Correctly add instance of a class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, composition

I have 3 class objects A, B, C. I have a property in class B called handleDropDown().

I have created a custom type

type PageObject = {
pageObject: A | B | C;
}

It can either be class A,B or C.

When try to access the handleDropDown from class B I get an error that

Property 'handleDropDown' does not exist on type 'A | B | C'.

I am new to typescript was wondering what I am doing wrong

```js
type Query = {
  name: string;
}

class BaseAll {

}

class BaseInfo {

}



class A extends BaseAll {
  query: Query;

  constructor(query: Query) {
    super();
    this.query = query;
  }
}



class B extends BaseAll {
  query: Query;

  constructor(query: Query) {
    super();
    this.query = query;
  }

  handleDropDown() {
    console.log('I am here')

  }
}


class C extends BaseAll {
  query: Query;

  constructor(query: Query) {
    super();
    this.query = query;
  }
}


type PageObject = {
  pageObject: A | B | C;
}

class Page {
  header: string;
  objs: {
    [key: string]: A | B | C
  } = {};


  constructor(text: string) {
    this.header = text;
  }

  setHeaderText(text: string) {
    return text
  }

  addObj(name: string, obj: A | B | C) {
    this.objs[name] = obj;
  }

}


let myQuery3 = {
  name: 'list'
};
let myQuery2 = {
  name: 'file'
};

let A1 = new A(myQuery3);
let A2 = new A(myQuery2);
let C1 = new C(myQuery2);
let C2 = new C(myQuery3);

let page1 = new Page("Page title Here");
page1.addObj('t1', A1);
page1.addObj('t2', A2);
page1.addObj('f1', C1);
page1.addObj('f2', C2);
console.log(page1.objs.t1.query);
console.log(page1.objs.t2.query);
console.log(page1.objs.f1.handleDropDown());
console.log(page1.objs.f2.handleDropDown());


//let page1_filter = new Filter("Dashboard", [],[]);
// page1.updateQuery(myQuery2);

console.log(page1);
```

Comment: You're calling the `handleDropDown()` function on a variable of a union type (`A | B | C`) and only one type in that union (`B`) has a `handleDropDown()` function declared. TypeScript helpfully points out that, according to your type definition, your `Page` might have objects that don't implement the function you're trying to call.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you for your reply. I want the property for only B and I don't want to declare it for A & C. As A & C might not have use for that property

Comment: Then check whether your object `instanceof B` to narrow the type before calling the function.

Comment: I tried this it worked:  ```page1.objs.f1 instanceof B? page1.objs.f1.handleDropDown() : null;``` Is that the correct way of handling it ?

Answer (score 1):

While a runtime check via `instanceof B` is always an option, I would consider  using an const object literal.

When dealing with const object literals, TS can infer precise type of that object.

```ts
interface Page {
  header: string;
  objs: {
    [key: string]: A | B | C;
  }
};

const A1 = new A(myQuery3);
const A2 = new A(myQuery2);
const B1 = new B(myQuery2);
const C2 = new C(myQuery3);

const page1 = {
  header: 'Page title Here',
  objs: {
    t1: A1,
    t2: A2,
    f1: B1,
    f2: C2
  }
} satisfies Page;
console.log(page1.objs.t1.query);
console.log(page1.objs.t2.query);
console.log(page1.objs.f1.handleDropDown());
console.log(page1.objs.f2.handleDropDown());  // Expected error
```

Please note that:

- inferred type if page1 is:

```ts
const page1: {
    header: string;
    objs: {
        t1: A;
        t2: A;
        f1: B;
        f2: C;
    };
}
```

- this code uncovers a bug in your code (in compile time) - you are trying to call `handleDropDown` on `f1` and `f2` of type `C` - which do not have these methods. This is an advantage over runtime check.
- I used TS 4.9 satisfies operator to still have type checking and code completion

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221002#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiKBeKBvAUFKA7AQwFsIAuKAZ2EQEs8BzAbiwF8ssBjAGwIoqgBCvCAEEuXTOzacefQcICSeAGYB7Sa3btuvfiKgQAHsAh4AJvyEVR4ybgCOCZOXhIQzHFA6q8VRHA5gVUQACkc3FycQAEo7XEo4SFDo5nioYAALGgoAOnDkNCh89082aW1ZSwNjUwt5azEJbAcoyLcPXG9fagCg0OK25Fjm%20IpEpBCUz1xM7LyowuLUqGlcDIJzLggAEURVMG3VAHc8SbjOnwpVLZyuVXoQgHIFKGIoDKQIR%20j2XDKtHRyADC1RM5kswkacQGsCiHS8lx6gWCYVasLcw2mCSSk2WMyyuWKizhpU0WDoJkQygIHGgAAUCPRoCMPgQzEhyH46ExPKoAEYAKwo5BGuAA2gBrCAgTnUbkAXXI%20gAPoIoKqgcsyh4sFtgFAiCBXMgAMyFEaEEjkR5cbLAR6sZh6g1GqIAJnNnktZCgj2UNC2DpYHi6VCgIgAjIU8BAjuGQobjSATVNQ-qRB70DG4yIE663G7U4jBFGs7HBHmk4XmGmoEDM-hy0DK1EUyHi2BGRBS3FWezENaGUz0jRgFsoAAJT6PAA0vMFwvO6QjSojc7SwDdSrd6-iyhXJd3uGUW7rbtJLEoBGA2X9EH4Q%20gNcu1wgt3uIU7TIjOX5QpywA-sURa%20K%2074PF%203a-guAFuvMGLPqBNx3BBXY-n%20uT7jk6ybDsewHMcpzRCBVzIR%20kHoTBJ7YRsZhbLs%20yHCckxTOwAD0bHOhRAD6-pcJS0blgAYgGlIhAARNsvAZHyqgEIgZjiTOUBivKM6qVMHFQBROSJGY14QEmLYFqxoZgShn5oSkQA)